# Ruby do-loop to break down an array/hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, loops

I made a self referring database using the `has_many :through` relationship:

```
**Product**
name


**Ingredient**
quantity
product_id
product_component_id
```

I can have an egg, carton of 12 eggs, and a flat of 16 cartons.

I am trying to write a loop that starts with a product and breaks down all the components of each product and those to the most basic state. The goal is to return an array of all the base products that go into any given product so the carton would return 12 eggs and the flat would return 192 Eggs.

I gave it a shot and this is how far I got:

```
def product_breakdown
  results = []
   ingredients.each do |ingredient|
     if ingredient.product_component_id == nil
        results += ingredient
     else
        Keep digging deeper?
     end
   end
  return results
end
```

I am missing a whole concept when it comes to using the loop. If anyone has an advise on the name of the concepts that this requires, I would be very appreciative.

edit in order to be more clear I copied the relationships of the database.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ingredients 
    has_many :product_components, :through => :ingredients 
end 

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product 
    belongs_to :product_component, class_name: "Product", :foreign_key => "product_component_id" 
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what `product_source` and `product_component` refer to?

Comment: class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :product_components, :through => :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_component, class_name: "Product", :foreign_key => "product_component_id"
end

Comment: Can you post that in the question body instead where it'll be properly formatted? Thanks!

Comment: No worries. So if I'm understanding this correctly, a sample relationship would be: Two products, "egg", and "carton", and then one ingredient, `quantity: 3, product: "egg", product_component: "carton"` which would represent 3 cartons of eggs?

Comment: And the `product_breakdown` method is an instance method on `Product` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `each_with_object` to build the array.  That way you don't even need the `results` variable, just return each_with_object's return value.

How do you differentiate between a unit, carton, and flat?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out!

For this simplified example the product.name is intended to be the differentiator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each ingredient has a `component` which can be `nil`, `Carton`, or `Flat`? And one carton always contains 12 units, and one flat 16 cartons? And a `source`, which is the type of ingredient (egg, milk, etc?)

In that case, I'd define a couple helper methods on `Ingredient`, an `as_unit` class method and a `unit_quantity` instance method:

```
def unit_quantity
  case product_component_id
  when nil
    quantity
  when CARTON_COMPONENT_ID
    12 * quantity
  when FLAT_COMPONENT_ID
    192 * quantity
  end
end

def self.as_unit ingredients
  source_ids = ingredients.map(&:product_source_id).uniq
  raise "Can't join different types together" if source_ids.count != 1

  source_id = source_ids.first
  quantity = ingredients.reduce(0) { |total, ingredient| total += ingredient.unit_quantity }

  Ingredient.new quantity: quantity, product_component_id: nil, product_source_id: source_id
end
```

That way, you can rewrite `products_breakdown` to be:

```
def products_breakdown ingredients
  ingredients.group_by(&:product_source_id).map do |_, ingredients|
    Ingredient.as_unit ingredients
  end
end
```

This should result in:

```
$ ingredients
#=> [<Ingredient: 3 Cartons of Egg>, <Ingredient: 2 Flats of Milk>, <17 Units of Egg>]
$ product_breakdown ingredients
#=> [<Ingredient: 53 Units of Egg>, <Ingredient: 384 Units of Milk>]
```

Is this at all what you were looking for? I'm not sure I fully understood your question...

Comment: I really appreciate the detail that you gave here. Unfortunately I am still learning how best ask questions in this world.

The goal of putting all the relationships in the database is because at scale the app will have to juggle hundreds of relationships that sometimes chang to the point that hard coding them in the system may not be feasible.